# TCheckListBox strange behaviour, not showing first char

Tags: delphi, tchecklistbox

So I have a CheckListBox with 6 Items :

```
Items.Strings = (
    'Banana'
    'Apple'
    'Pomelo'
    'Orange'
    'Peach'
    'BlueBarry')
```

If I want to show them then into a ShowMessage dialog, the message printed is.

```
'anana','pple','omelo','range','each','lueBarry'.
```

The procedure I use is this.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var I : Integer;
begin
     for I := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
          ShowMessage(CheckListBox1.Items.ValueFromIndex[I]);
end;
```

Why can't I get the first char from my Item?

Comment: Sure the strings are that way as show above? `.ValueFromIndex` should return a value from a `Name=Value` list. An item would be accessed by `CheckListBox1.Items[I]`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I want to retriev the Text from each item. Is there an other way to do it? Beside ValueFromIndex?

Comment: as show in my first comment `CheckListBox1.Items[I]`. But `.ValueFromIndex ` should return  empty strings with your shown content of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to insert items in the right way like this

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Banana');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Apple');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Pomelo');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Orange');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Peach');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('BlueBarry');
end;
```

the result will be:

[image]

then...

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var I : Integer;
begin
     for I := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
          ShowMessage(CheckListBox1.Items[I]);

end;
```

Comment: I did that, I insert the items from a DataSet in my program, but the property "ValueOfIndex[]" for some reason doesn't return the first Char.

Comment: Yes, i tried with Items[I] and works. Thank you, but still why does ValueOfIndex have that strange behaviour?

Comment: This really should be just *one* answer, rather than two. Here, you demonstrate using the `Items` property (without actually mentioning it), and in your other answer, you explain why `ValueFromIndex` is the wrong property for the intended task. It would be better to explicitly *say* that `Items` is what's needed, demonstrate it as you have here, and then explain what was wrong with the original code, as you did in the other answer. That would make a single good answer instead of two so-so answers. (The picture and the code for manually populating the list are irrelevant to *either* answer.)

Comment: In my opinion two answers are more clear than one, in this case, only one answer was too long in my opinion. When someone is searching for a solution, the best thing is to find a short solution that make easy and fast the understanding, where the user can copy , paste then try the solution...
The image attached shows that all the items are complete and not truncated, therefore the solution works fine...
Anyway I can't understand the reason of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use ValueFromIndex for your porpouse.

TStrings.ValueFromIndex

Return the value part of a string based on it's index.

Declaration

```
public property TStrings.ValueFromIndex : string
  read GetValueFromIndex
  write SetValueFromIndex;
```

Description

ValueFromIndex returns the value part of a string based on the string index. The value part are all characters in the string after the NameValueSeparator character, or all characters if the NameValueSeparator character is not present.

```
TStrings.NameValueSeparator
```

Value of the character used to separate name,value pairs

Declaration

```
public property TStrings.NameValueSeparator : Char
  read FNameValueSeparator
  write SetNameValueSeparator;
```

Description

NameValueSeparator is the character used to separate name,value pair. By default, this is the equal sign (=), resulting in Name=Value pairs.

It can be set to a colon for Name : Value pairs.

thake a look at the vcl source :O

```
function TStrings.GetValueFromIndex(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  if Index >= 0 then
    Result := Copy(Get(Index), Length(Names[Index]) + 2, MaxInt) else
    Result := '';
end;
```

Comment: The VCL source is undoubtedly buggy, but it is a forgivable error. I mean it does not handle the case when the list does not contain name/value pairs. So what?

Comment: so what?? so you cannot use ValueFromIndex for the porpouse exposed. Nothing else.

Comment: But... but... but... the purpose of the .ValueFromIndex property is something else. The buggy behavior is only that even something is returned, not that wrong value is returned.

Comment: The `Classes.TStrings` does not give this unwanted sideeffect since at least Delphi-XE.